# Jet creator music - EAS synth.dll

Tags: java, android, multimedia

I am trying to use the JET music player in Android to create music for my game. I am having trouble installing the eas synth plugin for Sonar 7 which I will use to edit the midi tracks.

I am using this guide to get everything installed so that I can edit my [music](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/sonivox/docs/JET_Authoring_Guidelines.html).

The problem is at point 3.1 Installing the EAS Synth Plugin I am supposed to install `EAS synth.dll` into the Sonar vst plugin folder.

Where can i find the `EAS synth.dll` file? It is definitely not included in the SDK! I found a file called `EADDLL.dll` in the `\tools\Jet\JetCreator` directory, but Sonar does not recognize it as a plugin.

I think JET and JET creator is ridiculously pour documented by google! Any help regarding JET creator would be appreciated! I'm hoping for some smart guy here who has successfully used jet creator.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. Very frustrating. The problem is that the included EASDLL.dll file is not actually a VST plugin. I wrote the a VST plugin that does the job and have published it here:

http://www.evanmallory.com/eas_vst/

Give it a try. I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Evan's app works AOK for me on Windows 7 64-bit using Reaper. Definitely worth grabbing if you want to compose using the actual EAS instruments. As for JetCreator itself, to get it working you will need to specifically run Python 2.5 with a compatible version of wxPython - on 64-bit Windows this means running 32-bit Python (since there's no 64-bit wxPython available for 2.5) but it does work, unlike JetCreator with Python 2.6 or higher which just refuses to play ball.

Answer (score 1):

*.dll files are for Windows only, the Linux equivalent is *.so, but the JET libraries area already installed on an Android device so you don't need to worry about it.  As for Google's documentation, that link is not a Google page, here is the [Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/media/index.html).  Here is what it says:

> Playing JET content The Android
>   platform includes a JET engine that
>   lets you add interactive playback of
>   JET audio content in your
>   applications. You can create JET
>   content for interactive playback using
>   the JetCreator authoring application
>   that ships with the SDK. To play and
>   manage JET content from your
>   application, use the JetPlayer class.
>
> For a description of JET concepts and
>   instructions on how to use the
>   JetCreator authoring tool, see the
>   JetCreator User Manual. The tool is
>   available fully-featured on the OS X
>   and Windows platforms and the Linux
>   version supports all the content
>   creation features, but not the
>   auditioning of the imported assets.
>
> Here's an example of how to set up JET
>   playback from a .jet file stored on
>   the SD card:

```
JetPlayer myJet = JetPlayer.getJetPlayer();
myJet.loadJetFile("/sdcard/level1.jet");
byte segmentId = 0;

// queue segment 5, repeat once, use General MIDI, transpose by -1 octave
myJet.queueJetSegment(5, -1, 1, -1, 0, segmentId++);
// queue segment 2
myJet.queueJetSegment(2, -1, 0, 0, 0, segmentId++);

myJet.play();
```

> The SDK includes an example
>   application — JetBoy — that shows how
>   to use JetPlayer to create an
>   interactive music soundtrack in your
>   game. It also illustrates how to use
>   JET events to synchronize music and
>   game logic. The application is located
>   at
>   /platforms/android-1.5/samples/JetBoy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question was a bit unclear...

I am trying to edit music on my computer using the music editing program Sonar 7. The music will be used in my game... In order to make the midi files compatible with android devices and JET Creator i need to use the EAS synth plugin for Sonar 7. The problem is that i cant find the "EAS Synth.dll" wich is needed for this. And yes, I have read trough all the documentation wich you are referring to :)

The plugin is described under section 3.1 in the guidelines:
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/sonivox/docs/JET_Authoring_Guidelines.html

Comment: Quick note: Instead of posting an answer as a follow-up, you should edit your original post.